# Dynamically generated DIVs missing class attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have created a table and I dynamically populate this table by generating `DIV`s. I want my table elements to be draggable so i'm using `Jquery.Ui` which requires the class to be specified with the correct name so that it can be dragged. However I find that only the first `DIV` has this class and the other generated ones don't which means they can't be dragged.

My code.

```
while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array ( $result ) ) {
                    echo '<div id="Cell" class="ui-widget-content">';
                    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="tbl" id="tblst"   value="' . $row [0] . '"  />';
                    echo '<p>' . $row [0] . '</p>';
                    echo '</div>';
                }
```

Output via inspect element.

[image: DIV]

How can I fix this so that all the elements generated are draggable??

Comment: What is your javascript that is calling `draggable()`?
I'm willing to bet it is `$('#Cell').draggable()`, right?

Comment: Yes correct because its `Cell` that I want to drag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JS is targeting an element by ID

```
$('#Cell').draggable()
```

So it's assuming only one element is named #Cell.  Remove the Id Cell since its invalid HTML, and echo it out this way:

```
echo '<div class="draggable-cell ui-widget-content">';
```

And change JS to target class instead:

```
$('.draggable-cell').draggable()
```

Now it will target multiple elements.

Comment: I was using `Class ="Cell"` but the draggable elements also need the class  to be specified. Your suggestion didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would want to be able to track the cells at some point, so please try this:

```
<div id="FirstRow" class="Row"></div>
```

With this javascript:

```
function createCells() {
    var counter = 0;
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $("#FirstRow").append('<div id="cell_' + counter + '" class="ui-widget-content"><p>' + $row[0] + '</p></div>');
        counter++;
    }
    $("#FirstRow").children().draggable();
}
$(function () {
    createCells();
});
```

[JSFiddle Link to code](http://jsfiddle.net/JonTurlington/j9vc7ek8/)